# How to Create drop down list with multiple selection using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

How to Create drop down list(from database) with multiple selection in asp.net mvc 5 using bootstrap.

Comment: Your question might be too broad. Which parts do you have already working? Do you have the dropdown with single selection in place?

Comment: If you share what you have tried, it would be helpful. And be specific what you are asking.

Comment: I am working with Asp.net MVC 5 with entityframework. I have already created single selection. I want multi selection using Bootstrap.

Comment: Googling yields a lot of results for this, did you try any? http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support (Stack Overflow questions should deal with a concrete problem, they are not tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a dropdown which enables multi select you could use a ListBox as following.

```
@Html.ListBox("Lsystem", null, new {style="width:100%", size = @ViewBag.size })
```

This how you can use ListBox in Razor. In the controller you will have to add the following

```
ViewBag.Lsystem = new MultiSelectList(db.Lsystem.ToList(), "LsystemID", "LsystemName");
```